# Check the correct checkbox according to value fetched from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for a project. On the html side, I have 3 checkboxes in which I will see which is the checked one and store the value in database. Now I want to fetch the value and checked the corresponding checkbox.

My checkboxes is as below

```
<div class="span2">
   <label class="radio">
      <input class="attrInputs" type="radio" name="shoulder" value="flat">
      Flat
   </label>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/126x126/cbcbcb" class="push-top">
</div>
<div class="span2">
   <label class="radio">
      <input class="attrInputs" type="radio" name="shoulder" value="regular">
      Regular
   </label>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/126x126/cbcbcb" class="push-top">
</div>
<div class="span2 border-right">
   <label class="radio">
      <input class="attrInputs" type="radio" name="shoulder" value="sloped">
      Sloped
   </label>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/126x126/cbcbcb" class="push-top">
</div>
```

So for example if I checked input element with value sloped, the value sloped will be stored in the database, when user logs in, its preloaded with its checked input of the value sloped

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: I think you need to read up on [HTML forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), [data entry in CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert) and [CodeIgniter's form helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay without your controller and how you're returning the data I am going to give you the basics of how this works. Essentially you're going to be checking the value of shoulder and determining the appropriate box. So in your controller you'd send data to the view something like this (again I have no idea what your db or tables looks like so this is example only).

Controller:

```
$this->load->model('someModel');
//the following populates the formData variable with an array from your database.
//I am going to assume you know how to do this.
$data['formData'] = $this->someModel->getData();
$this->load->view('someView',$data);
```

View, while it can be easier to use CI's built in form handler it's not necessary so I'll just use your code for example.

```
<div class="span2">
   <label class="radio">
      <input class="attrInputs" type="radio" name="shoulder" value="flat" 
       checked="<?=$formdata['shoulder'] == 'flat' ? 'checked' : '' ;?>">
      Flat
   </label>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/126x126/cbcbcb" class="push-top">
</div>
<div class="span2">
   <label class="radio">
      <input class="attrInputs" type="radio" name="shoulder" value="regular" 
       checked="<?=$formdata['shoulder'] == 'regular' ? 'checked' : '' ;?>">
      Regular
   </label>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/126x126/cbcbcb" class="push-top">
</div>
<div class="span2 border-right">
   <label class="radio">
      <input class="attrInputs" type="radio" name="shoulder" value="sloped" 
       checked="<?=$formdata['shoulder'] == 'sloped' ? 'checked' : '' ;?>">
      Sloped
   </label>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/126x126/cbcbcb" class="push-top">
</div>
```

What the above code is doing is using a shorthand if statement to determine which box should be checked. In each one it checks if the value of 'shoulder' that your database returned is the same as the checkbox and sets it's checked value to checked if it is and blank if it isn't.

It also uses php shorttags, so if those aren't enabled on your server either enable them or adjust the php tags to read:

```
 checked="<?php echo ($formdata['shoulder'] == 'flat' ? 'checked' : '') ;?>"
```